# Difficulty filtering by Select Column

Tags: sql, select, filter

I'm going to apologize in advance. I basically stumble through SQL as projects need done but my knowledge is rather lacking, so I apologize for any incorrect terminology or poor syntax.
I would appreciate it if anyone would be able to help me out.

I have the following query.

```
WITH BusinessDayCalc
AS
(
    SELECT
            EstimatedClosingDate AS EstimatedClosingDate
              from SampleDB

)
SELECT
    a.*,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), EstimatedClosingDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk,GETDATE(), EstimatedClosingDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, EstimatedClosingDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(Select Count(*)  FROM Holiday Where Date >= GETDATE() AND Date < EstimatedClosingDate)

  AS BusinessDaysUntil
FROM BusinessDayCalc a
Where EstimatedClosingDate > GetDate() AND EstimatedClosingDate < (GetDate()+17)
```

I have also attached pics of the current [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynuZG.png) and the [Holiday Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5pRa.png) that is being referenced.

My issue is that I would like to be able to filter my data to show any data that is 8 or 12 business days out, however, I am unable to pull through the column name or have SQL recognize the BusinessDaysUntil column.

Would someone be able to help me out? Once I get this squared away, the rest of the project should go smoothly.

Comment: To avoid our assumptions, where are you applying filter on *BusinessDaysUntil* column? Is there another query you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a derived column in the `WHERE` clause.
Also you are using a rather useless CTE which returns only 1 column of the table `SampleDB`.
Instead create a CTE with the query and then select from it and filter:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    EstimatedClosingDate,
    (DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), EstimatedClosingDate) + 1)
    -(DATEDIFF(wk,GETDATE(), EstimatedClosingDate) * 2)
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, EstimatedClosingDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, EstimatedClosingDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    -(Select Count(*)  FROM Holiday Where Date >= GETDATE() AND Date < EstimatedClosingDate) AS BusinessDaysUntil
  FROM SampleDB
  WHERE EstimatedClosingDate > GetDate() AND EstimatedClosingDate < (GetDate()+17)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE BusinessDaysUntil > ?
```

Replace `BusinessDaysUntil > ?` with the filter that you want to apply.

Comment: needs AS BusinessDaysUntil just prior to FROM SampleDB

Comment: @donPablo no worries

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the help. However, my concern is, that I do have other columns that I pull data for, I just removed them for security and simplicity of the example. How do I go about adding additional fields to pull from the SampleDB?

Comment: @forpas, I apologize for that. I got a bit excited when it appeared to have worked, but then after rereading your answer, and trying to add an additional column, I noticed my question posted from above. How do I display more data from the SampleDB?

Comment: You can select as many columns as you want. In the cte write: `SELECT EstimatedClosingDate, column1, column2, ....`

Comment: Disregard. I was looking at the wrong spot. It works perfectly. Thank you. I am marking it as accepted. Thank you again and sorry for the confusion.